# Fine-tuning mod_security rule 942100

Tags: mod-security2

I am using mod_security 2.9.3, together with the Core Rule Set version 3.2.3, both as packaged for Debian 10 ('buster' – yes, I know this is reaching the end of support), and I'm getting occasional false positives from rule **942100** (one of the libinjection rules).   This rule is also proving one of the most useful for filtering genuine attempts at SQL injections attacks, so I'm keen not to disable it entirely.  (I know how to do that and I have verified that it does solve the problem.)  Ideally I'd like to fine-tune it instead to tweak the test that is yielding the false positive.  I'm looking for help with that.

A typical log entry looks something like this:

> Message: Warning. detected SQLi using libinjection with fingerprint '1kn&n' [fil
> e "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "68"] [id "942100"] [msg "SQL Injection Attack Detected via libinjection"] [data "Matched Data: 1kn&n found within ARGS:details: XXXXXXXXXXXXX"]

(I'm afraid I've had to redact the `details` argument as it invariably contains personal data, though I know that will not help people answer my question.  The argument is typically a single short sentence containing a few numbers, personal names and short words, here 'and' and 'each', and little to no punctuation.)

I've looked at the recipe in `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/` and I was expecting to find a regular expression or something similar, but there isn't one.  The only comment is a reference to https://libinjection.client9.com/ which does not resolve.  Does the fingerprint '1kn&n' somehow reference the particular pattern that's triggering?  Is there a way of looking that up somewhere?  And if so, is it possible to use this to selectively whitelist parts of the rule?

Comment: You can write an exclusion rule which will whitelist such requests. I can help you with that but i need more information - at least the exact URL (you can censor the domain name).

Comment: @azurit – The URL is simply `https://example.com/submit.php`.  It's a POST request to that URL without a query string.  I certainly don't want to whitelist that URL unconditionally as it's one of the most used (and most attacked) URLs on the site.  I want to understand what precisely in the `details` parameter is triggering this rule, and then look at how to disable that specific test.

Answer (score -1):

You can whitelist such requests using exclusion rule like this, just set the correct domain name in the first line (put it inside file `REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf`):

```
SecRule SERVER_NAME "@streq example.com" \
    "id:9999001,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@streq /submit.php" \
        "t:none,\
        ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942100;ARGS:details"
```

This specific exclusion rule is disabling rule `942100` for POST/GET argument `details` on URL `example.com/submit.php`.

Comment: This isn't answering the question.  I don't want to whitelist the URL.  I want to work out what exactly is triggering the in the rule and then work out how to remove that particular part of the rule.

Comment: What you want is not possible. Using exclusions, such as the one i wrote for you, is the way how situations like yours are resolved.

Comment: – Are you saying it's not even possible to see what exactly has matched?  I'm sorry, but I don't believe you.

Comment: It's not possible to 'read' it from modsecurity logs. Try contacting libinjection authors.

Comment: – So what does the fingerprint '1kn&n' mean?  It must mean something or they wouldn't include it in the logs.  And please don't patronise me.

Comment: We (the Core Rule Set developers, i'm one of them) are including it in the logs because it is the only thing which modsecurity is outputing when blocking using libinjection (and it is probably something which libinjection itself is outputting and modsec is only passing it by). I'm not an expert on libinjection (and no one of CRS devs is) so you probably need to contact libinjection authors directly. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not criticising you in any way for not knowing what the fingerprint means – I don't know either – but it seems highly likely it's the key to understanding exactly what he rule is doing.  I don't see how I can accept an answer to my question that doesn't address this.  Sorry!